# ASP.NET Core Web API StringLocalizer doesn't gives the value from the resx file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, localization

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project with one .resx file to provide some strings in German language. I want to use these strings in a controller. I have followed the documentation to use `IStringLocalizer`. The controller is in the namespace `StringLocalizer.Controllers` and is named `ValuesController` and looks like the following:

```
namespace StringLocalizer.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        private IStringLocalizer m_Localizer;

        public ValuesController(IStringLocalizerFactory _localizerFactory)
        {
            m_Localizer = _localizerFactory.Create("StringLocalizer.Controllers.Values",
                          System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);
        }

        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<string> Get()
        {
            string result = m_Localizer["Hello"].Value;

            return result;
        }
}
```

So my localization file is named `StringLocalizer.Controllers.Values.de.resx`.

The `ConfigureService` in my `Startup.cs` looks like:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("de")
            };

            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "de", uiCulture: "de");
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });         

        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
    }
```

And in the `Configure` Method I have added this

```
var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);
```

The problem now is that it looks like that the resource can't be found, because the value in

```
m_Localizer["Hello"].Value
```

is set to the indexer value. But in the .resx file it is `HalloWelt`.

Comment: @marc_s, please tell me did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution yet. I'm currently working on a more important problem in the project. But I will come back to this in the next days to find a solution.